# how to change the headers in cloudfare

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudflare

I am trying to recieve header with the "Content-Type":"text/css".but I'm getting "text/plain" in response . this is my code

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})


async function handleRequest(request) {
   return new Response('body{display:none}', {status: 200},{headers:{"Content-Type":"text/css"}});

  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

> In responses, a Content-Type header tells the client what the content type of the returned content actually is. Browsers will do MIME sniffing in some cases and will not necessarily follow the value of this header; to prevent this behavior, the header X-Content-Type-Options can be set to nosniff.